# Serve image from browser-cache when re-fetching an <img> using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, fetch, browser-cache, cache-control, netlify

I have a problem getting an image out of the browser cache.

Simple scenario:

- The DOM downloads an image using an `<img>` tag
- Using `fetch()` on the `img.src` doesn't serve it from the browser cache

An example: https://fetch-img-from-cache.netlify.com

In this example I let Netlify use their default headers with Cache-Control set to `public, max-age=0, must-revalidate`. In my understanding that should only lead to a conditional get, with a response of 304 (Not Modified), that lets the browser use the cached image. (Netlifys explanation: [better-living-through-caching](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2017/02/23/better-living-through-caching/))

This is how it looks:

```
    <main>
        <div id="images">
            <img id="samplePhoto" src="assets/340_AppleiPhoneXSMax_IMG_E7156.jpg">
        </div>
    </main>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.querySelector('#samplePhoto').addEventListener('load', fetchImgFromCache);

        function fetchImgFromCache(e) {
            const img = e.target;

            fetch(e.target.src) // Failing to hit cache
                .then(....)
```

[image: Chrome Devtools showing superflous downloading of image]

Comment: I would like to suggest to not care too much about this, if you link to static image sources the browser will handle the caching himself. If you want to do this you probably need a place where you save the cache uri (or the whole pic) and next time you visit the site check if there is something at the local storage.

Comment: @efkah I have a personal reason good enough to care about it :) Also, I'm not after what happens on subsequent page loads but rather the first.